# Sending arrays (LaserScan msg) in rosserial

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, ros-kinetic, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to send data from a temperature sensor using the intensities array within a LaserScan message (this will then be manipulated within ROS further. using laserScan does make sense later down the road).

The sensor gives out an array of 64 numbers, I extract the ones I want and put them into another array, this array is then assigned to the intensities field of the message.

However, when I try to compile the code I get the error:

```
exit status 1
cannot convert 'float' to 'sensor_msgs::LaserScan::_intensities_type* {aka float*}' in assignment
```

Code:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <ros/time.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_AMG88xx.h>

//***ROS requrments***//
ros::NodeHandle  nh;

sensor_msgs::LaserScan Temp_distance;
ros::Publisher pub_dis("AMG833", &Temp_distance);

const float angle = 60;
float minimum_angle = 0 - (((angle * 71) / 4068) / 2);
float max_angle = (((angle * 71) / 4068) / 2);
float inc = (((angle * 71) / 4068)/8);

char frameid[] = "/AMG833id";


//***AMG8833 requrments***//
Adafruit_AMG88xx amg;
float pixels[AMG88xx_PIXEL_ARRAY_SIZE];
float middle[7];


void setup()
{
  //***ROS requrments***//
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pub_dis);

  //***AMG8833 requrments***//
  delay(100); //sensor boot
}

void loop()
{
  //read all the pixels
  amg.readPixels(pixels);
  

 for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
 {
  int pixelval = 32-i;
  middle[i] = pixels[pixelval];
 }
  
  
  Temp_distance.angle_min = minimum_angle;
  Temp_distance.angle_max = max_angle;
  Temp_distance.intensities = middle[7];
  Temp_distance.header.frame_id = frameid;
  Temp_distance.header.stamp = nh.now();
  Temp_distance.angle_increment = inc;
  Temp_distance.scan_time = 0.1;
  
  pub_dis.publish( &Temp_distance );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Sorry if i've got the formatting of the post wrong, (feel free to fix if necessary mods)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310015/sending-arrays-(laserscan-msg)-in-rosserial/) by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-05**:\

> Sorry if i've got the formatting of the post wrong, (feel free to fix if necessary mods)

I've fixed it this time for you. Next question will be closed if you don't format it properly.

Use the *Preformatted Text* button for that (the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-05**:\

> ```
> Temp_distance.intensities = middle[7];
> ```

this is most likely the problem: `middle[7]` is a single `float`, not an array. The error msg tells you that the field expects an array (or really a `float*`).

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
Ok, so removing the [7] from the line:

```
Temp_distance.intensities = middle[7];
```

to:

```
Temp_distance.intensities = middle;
```

seemed to fix the compiling issue. However, while rosserial does publish the message type. The intensities array shows as empty (shows [] in ros).

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
And, I'm sorry, I'm afraid I am not familiar with float* as a variable type, how is it different from float? And I couldn't find any reference page to it, is there a way to convert a float to a float*? As the sensor gives out an array as a float array of 64 characters, and this cannot be changed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-05**:
I would suggest to take a look at the [rosserial/Overview/Limitations](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations) page. It discusses the limitations of `rosserial` and how to deal with them. Lists and arrays work differently between `rosserial` and `roscpp`.

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
Thanks, I have looked at it, but I msut admit, I don't understand the example given, and don't know how to apply it in this case. The array test example in arduino, as far as I can tell does not publish an array, only subscribes to one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will say that using the laser_scan message for something that is not a laser scan is not a good idea. This is breaking the semantics of the message type completely. There is almost certainly a better way of doing this even if you need to make your own custom message type.

However the problem you're having at the moment is cause because you're not manipulating arrays correctly. The type of the laser_scan.intensities variable is a pointer to a float so to set it to point to your middle array you should remove the lvalue so it decomposes to a pointer.

```
Temp_distance.intensities = middle;
```

Hope this helps

UPDATE:

I've just checked the [documentation for rosserial regarding arrays](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations#Arrays) and you need to add an extra parameter describing the length of an array when working in rosserial. So in your case you'll need to add an extra value as shown below:

```
Temp_distance.intensities = middle;
Temp_disrance.intensities_length = 7;
```

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-05**:
You're right about the OP not populating the `intensities` field correctly, but this is a `rosserial` context: arrays and lists in ROS IDL are mapped to `malloc`ed arrays there, not to `std::vector`.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-05**:
You're right. Fixed

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
While changing to your suggestion did allow the code to compile, as mentioned above in the comments, the field when in ros is empty. The messsage displays as (shorted for post length):

```
intensities: []
```

This data will be combined with a laser scanner distance measurments as a stop-gap for Rviz

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-05**:
I've updated my answer with the solution to this for you now.

Regarding the message type, a PointCloud2 with a custom point type would be the correct way to go about this and could be visualised in RVIZ without any problems.

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
Thank you, I was missing the intensities_length message, it now prints. (although it need to be `Temp_distance.intensities_length = 8;` as the array starts at 0)
For some reason it prints every value as -511.75, I don't know why yet. But I suspect thats a different issue.

Thanks all for the help!

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
And thank you, I will likely use PointCloud2 as the enxt logical step then, as most of the work for laser scan is already done and they should be largely the same issues getting both to work

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-05**:
I'm glad you got this working. Although I believe the array is still 7 elements long regardless of starting at index 0.

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
What makes you say that? When I echoed the message within ros and the array onl had 7 elements until I increased the value to 8. Or are you saying the array i add only had 7 elements?
Thanks
Edward

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-05**:
Yes the `middle` array you declared here:

```
float middle[7];
```

Only has 7 elements. If you set the length to 8 you'll be printing out the contents of a random memory address.

**Comment by [Edie00773](https://answers.ros.org/users/38858/edie00773/) on 2018-12-05**:
Sorry, yes you are right. I just checked through the ard reference again. Thanks for the catch